# Glass Fish asadmin start-domain fails

Tags: java, windows, glassfish

I installed Glass Fish 3.1.2 and I worked fine, but after some days I got this error message when I tried to start the Glass Fish server

### any help to fix this issues

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fefc1f3bdc, pid=6464, tid=5812
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [chtbrkg.dll+0x23bdc]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: I think chtbrkg.dll is some kind of malware. You should try to scan your system with an antivirus to see if it gets detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be fixed by modifying any GlassFish configuration. The problem is, as the output states, ***outside the JVM in native code***.

There should be extra output below what you've pasted that begins with

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
```

Underneath, there should be a stack which contains the problematic frame: `C  [chtbrkg.dll+0x23bdc]`

There may be some more information in there to help you pin down what is wrong, but this is a very low-level fundamental problem with the JVM itself. Something has clearly changed with the platform - perhaps a Windows update or something similar has modified the `chtbrkg.dll` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply for all, finally I had to format the machine after doing lots of changes. Now works fine, can run GlassFish. Tried many ways but could not be solved until I reinstall Windows.